# Styling dynamically generated divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, styles, onload, event-bubbling

The following code works:

```
$('#class').on('mouseover', '.ado', function() {
 var colors = ["#848484", "#088a08", "#ffbf00", "#a901d8", "#ff0000", "#0000ff"];
    var i = 0;
    $('.ado').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({'border-left-width' : '5px', 'border-left-style' : 'solid', 'border-left-color' : colors[i]});
    i = (i + 1)%colors.length;
  });
});
```

divs with the class`.ado` are generated dynamically in the div `#class` (which exists on page load) and the code styles each instance with a different colored left border.   The problem is I can't get this to work on load - only on mouseover (or click, etc.).  I understand from the jQuery site that 'load' is one of the events that doesn't bubble, so `.on('load', '.ado', function() {` doesn't work.  How can I get the styling to be applied on page load without any user action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually trigger the mouseover event for those elements

```
$('#class .ado').trigger('mouseover')
```

Comment: 'setTimeout(function() {
$('.ado').trigger('mouseover');
},3000);' - this works, but the `setTimeout` function is a not good idea.  Using `$(document).ready(function()` doesn't work, perhaps because the dynamic loading follows a geolocation (with the pop up for user consent) - and this is why setTimeout is probably not the right solution either (don't know how long the user will take to accept).  I've tried `('#class').ajaxStop(function()` - but no luck there either.  It seems I need to find a sign that the divs have loaded after the user has accepted the geolocation.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sideroxylon how is the `.ado` elements loaded, is it via a ajax request?

Comment: Solved!  I had put your code in the wrong place - I have added it immediately after the code that appends the `.ado` class.  Works perfectly now.  Thanks.

Comment: @sideroxylon yes that how it had to be

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/